# How to display svg, png, jpeg images in React-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I used `<Image>` tag to display images in my project, but it's not displaying the svg images on the iOS, so i used `<SvgUri>` from the [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) instead of `<Image>`, but now if i try to show any images other than svg, it's throwing error. Is there any library to display both svg and non-svg images on iOS & android devices?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg
try this

ex -

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';
    
    export default () => (
      <SvgUri
        width="50%"
        height="500%"
        uri="http://uri/img.svg"
      />
    );
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same, but it's only working for svg images, if i put a jpeg or png url, then it's throwing `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'source.length')`

Comment: I can't believe it's not asked around as much. But have you found a solution to this @Srinath? How to render both png and svg in a same view component?

Comment: @sanjeev at the end we decided to render two different components for svgs & pngs, we couldn't find any other better solution